# Jenkins SSH Host/User Certificates workflow

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ansible

How to setup SSH Cert signing process every time Ansible stage runs?
I have pipeline which creates VM's with the Terraform and then runs Ansible. At cloud-init stage Host keys are created and signed as well public User CA key are configured.
Client/Host CA authorities are configured in the HashiCorp Vault.
So, at this point, no matter what VM's are provisioned, i can SSH into every of them as i have `@cert-authority *.example.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAA...` set globally in `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`. All i need to do is to create new key and to sign it because my TTL is quite short.
But this does not work in Jenkins.
Jenkins stores all SSH keys under `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh` and by default there is nothing.
If just for the testing reasons i do copy my personal user keys and certificate + ssh config file into `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh`, then Jenkins can run Ansible happily.
But, i can't generate, sign and copy the jenkins keys every time i do some commit in my infra repo. Creating long living certs also does not smell good.

What is the idiomatic workflow for SSH Certificate signing and rotation?

Comment: This one has probably more chances to get answered on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Other solution came into my mind.

Create bash script `/etc/vault/sign-jenkins-cert.sh`

```bash
#cat <<EOT >> /etc/vault/sign-jenkins-cert.sh
#!/bin/bash

set -eu -o pipefail

VAULT_ADDR='https://vault.example.com'
SSH_PUB_KEY_PATH='/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub'
SSH_CERT_PATH='/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub'
ROLE_ID='<jenkins-role-id>'  # At cloud-init/kickstart stage this should be baked in
SECRET_ID='<jenkins-secret-id>'  # At cloud-init/kickstart stage this should be baked in

main () {
  local VAULT_TOKEN=$(vault_signin "${ROLE_ID}" "${SECRET_ID}")
  local SSH_PUB_KEY=$(cat "${SSH_PUB_KEY_PATH}")

  sign_ssh_cert "${VAULT_TOKEN}" "${SSH_PUB_KEY}" "${SSH_CERT_PATH}"

  chmod 0640 "${SSH_CERT_PATH}"
}

vault_signin () {
  local ROLE_ID=$1
  local SECRET_ID=$2

  local RES=$(curl -s --request POST \
    --data '{"role_id": "'"${ROLE_ID}"'", "secret_id": "'"${SECRET_ID}"'"}' \
    ${VAULT_ADDR}/v1/auth/approle/login | jq -r .auth.client_token)

  local RT=$?
  if [ "$RT" == "0" ]; then
    echo $RES
  else
    echo "Login with role $ROLE_ID failed. RT:$RT $RES"
    echo ""
  fi
}

sign_ssh_cert () {
  local VAULT_TOKEN="$1";
  local PUB_KEY="$2";
  local CERT_PATH="$3";

  curl -s \
    --header "X-Vault-Token: ${VAULT_TOKEN}" \
    --request POST \
    --data '{"public_key": "'"${PUB_KEY}"'", "cert_type": "user"}' \
    ${VAULT_ADDR}/v1/ssh-client-signer/sign/clientrole | jq -r .data.signed_key > "${CERT_PATH}"
}

main "$@"; exit
#EOT
```

Then set the permissions to `0644` and root ownership.

```bash
sudo chown root. /etc/vault/sign-jenkins-cert.sh && sudo chmod 0644 /etc/vault/sign-jenkins-cert.sh
```

Then create Systemd unit `/etc/systemd/system/sign-jenkins-certificate.service`

```bash
#cat <<EOT >> /etc/systemd/system/sign-jenkins-certificate.service
[Unit]
Description=Sign a new host cert on boot, then daily
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh /etc/vault/sign-jenkins-cert.sh
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=20
Type=forking
#EOT
```

Also set the permissions to `0644` and root ownership.

Then create the timer unit `/etc/systemd/system/sign-jenkins-certificate.timer`

```bash
#cat <<EOT >> /etc/systemd/system/sign-jenkins-certificate.timer
[Unit]
Description=Sign a new host cert on boot, then daily
[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily
Persistent=true
Unit=sign-jenkins-certificate.service
[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
#EOT
```

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html#Calendar%20Events

Verify

```bash
systemd-analyze verify /etc/systemd/system/sign-jenkins-certificate.timer
```

Enable and start timer

```bash
systemctl enable sign-jenkins-certificate.timer && \
systemctl start sign-jenkins-certificate.timer && \
systemctl status sign-jenkins-certificate.timer
```

For those who sits behind hardened proxy be sure your proxy does not block `curl` User-Agent in the Vault ACL.

This solution utilizes Vault AppRole for the authentication and the Systemd to run the signing service and there is no need for Vault agent on the Jenkins host.

This could be valid solution. But maybe there is something better?

Comment: The thing to pay attention to is to limit Jenkins ability to connect to any host in the network.

Answer (score 0):

I will list the "BAD" solution by myself. Bad, because key rotation there is mannual and TTL most likely will be long because we are lazy.

In the Vault you need to create a new "jenkins" SSH role with the TTL like `52w`

Then, ideally on the Jenkins host itself you need to create new keys.

```sh
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521 -f /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa -C "jenkins@jenkins-01"
```

Then singn it by Vault

```sh
vault write -field=signed_key ssh-client-signer/sign/jenkinsrole public_key=/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub > /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub
```

This means that Vault should be on the system. ... it's a dilemma - do you want to copy ssh keys (including private) over the network, which smells a bit, or you want to install Vault on the Jenkins machine. It's up to you.

After you have `id_ecdsa-cert.pub` certificate you can inspect it with `ssh-keygen -Lf /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub` and see is the Validity period, principals, etc. right.

Because most likely there will be drifts in the infrastructure, storing SSH config statically in the `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/config` will be painful.

Instead you can create `ansible-ssh.cfg` file with the content like

```yaml
Host bastion
  HostName bastion.example.com
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  CertificateFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub
  Port 22
  Protocol 2
  User fedora
  LogLevel INFO
```

This file can be (should be) located alongside with the rest of Ansible code.

Then, in the `ansible.cfg` file include SSH stanza

```yaml
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -F ./ansible-ssh.cfg
```

This way Ansible will pick up always up to date SSH configs.

If you use Terraform then it is possible dynamically update SSH config file to include new hosts and what not.

This solution is not tied to the Vault. It can be done quite easily with the `ssh-keygen` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I did something simliar.  The core of my system is a python script that that takes a users regular credentials (username/password), authenticates with Vault with those credentials and then uploads the user's public key (id_rsa.pub) and saves the returned certificate (id_rsa-cert.pub).  One of the main uses of this script is to give people access to build machines for troubleshooting.  We pair the process up with a generic account with either Admin rights (windows) or passwordless sudo (linux).  On linux we lock the password and on Windows we have a background process to rotate the password to something random.

For triggering Ansible from Jenkins, I create a new ssh key pair in a .ssh folder inside the working directory.  I then execute the script (this time I use an approle role-id/secret-id rather than username/password). In the vars file I set the ansible_ssh_private_key_file pointed to the newly generate private key which gives Ansible permissions to access to alternate-root account on the target machine.

I have the python script setup to be deployed through pypi, yum, apt and chocolatey to make it easy to install.

Comment: Thank you very much of sharing some additional ideas. Like you implicitly stated, with my approach i need to be careful about the Jenkins access scope. Currently it can access any host it wants which is BIG concern to me.
I am currently in bit different set of tasks, but i will revisit this quite soon. You gave me hint about scoping access from the working dir.